# Using $t0 value in !eb windbg command to write physical memory

Tags: windbg

I'm writing a WinDbg script to write some physical memory, running it in kernel debug mode, using the !ed command.

!ed is working fine when I run it manually with given values e.g. `!ed 9182f084 8`

I'd now like to run this in a script where the value to write comes from a pseudo-register. But the following does not work:

```
r $t0=8
!ed 9182f084 @$t0
```

I can't quite figure out what value it is writing in this case, but it is demonstrably not the integer value 8 that I am hoping for.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't work for me either. It looks like the !ed command is parsing the arguments incorrectly. You can specify something entirely invalid and it just silently ignores the command. For example, I don't even get an error with this:

```
kd> !ed 4318b20 XYZ
```

Aside from writing your own version of !ed, the only way I can think to get around it is to use an alias:

```
kd> r @$t0 = 8
kd> as /x ${/v:t0Val} @$t0
kd> !ed 4318b20 ${t0Val}
kd> !dd 4318b20 L1
# 4318b20 00000008
```

Pretty ridiculous way to specify "8", but it works if you're trying to put this into a script.